# how to Use RoundedImageView For Picasso in android

Tags: java, android, maven

i Want To Load Image From Picasso Library in RoundedImageView

I am Taking Refrence From https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView

I Really Unable To Understand How To Use For RoundedImageView

Can You please Tell Me How To use..I m Unable To understand..how to use

When I set Layout

```
<com.makeramen.RoundedImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/photo1"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:corner_radius="30dip"
        app:border_width="2dip"
        app:border_color="#333333"
        app:mutate_background="true"
        app:oval="true" />
```

instead Of ImageView...Giving Error ...

i dowloaded Java.doc.jar of roundedImageview from here
http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.makeramen%22%20AND%20a%3A%22roundedimageview%22

and add to the libs folder and build path

After Adding ...no resourc Found

update

```
//tv_gender.setText(Gender);
          iv = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        tv_intrseted.setText(IntrestedIn);
    //  Button logout=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.logout);
        RoundedImageView iv = new RoundedImageView(context);
        iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        iv.setCornerRadius(10);
        iv.setBorderWidth(2);
        iv.setBorderColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        iv.setMutateBackground(true);
        iv.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        iv.setBackground(backgroundDrawable);
        iv.setOval(true);
```

if I use Like This giving error ..Can not be Resolved RoundedImageView

Comment: @Prag'sシ  I posted My Layout part ...I use That Instead Of ImageView
givign error no Resource Found...

Comment: your java code dear..

Comment: [https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView)

Answer (score 1):

Try to Use the library available try using 
https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView

for the rounded ImageView in android.First try to create a basic one.[Androidgreeve](http://androidgreeve.blogspot.in/2014/09/facebook-messanger-like-profile-image.html) here i found a article on creating roundImageview as in facebook messanger

Comment: https://github.com/pavlospt/CircleView here is an another one for u to try and implement

Answer (score 0):

```
This is the procedure, what i followed for one of my project. Please, have a look. It may lead you to find the solution as per your requirement.

Create a class `RoundedTransform` and paste this code.

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;

import com.squareup.picasso.Transformation;

public class RoundedTransform implements Transformation {
@Override
public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
if (squaredBitmap != source) {
source.recycle();
}

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, source.getConfig());

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint();
BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap,
BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
paint.setShader(shader);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);

float r = size / 2f;
canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);

squaredBitmap.recycle();
return bitmap;
}

@Override
public String key() {
return "circle";
}
}


Then while calling the image view in your Activity,call as follows 

        iv = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        String imageUrl = "image";
        String url = "Pass your url";   
            if(url!=null){                              
                imageUrl = url;
            }

            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageUrl).fit().centerCrop().transform(new RoundedTransform()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).error(R.drawable.ic_launcher).into((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a transformation for Picasso.

```
Transformation transformation = new RoundedTransformationBuilder()
          .borderColor(Color.BLACK)
          .borderWidthDp(3)
          .cornerRadiusDp(30)
          .oval(false)
          .build();

Picasso.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .fit()
    .transform(transformation)
    .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit them to:

```
app:riv_corner_radius="30dip"

app:riv_border_width="2dip"
```

See [this](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView) for more info.